# How to use regex to get multiple occurrences of formula in PHP

Tags: php, regex, multiple-occurrence

I want to extract each arithmetic formula from this string:

```
+100*25-30
```

I used this regex:

```
preg_match_all("/(([\*\+\-\/])([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*))+/", "+100*25-30", $match);
```

It is capturing only last occurrence which is -30
but if I enter space before operator like this: +100 *25 -30, it is capturing all correctly, but I should do it without space. How to do it?

Comment: You have this `(...)+`. Just remove every thing except `...`. [See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/h0VnTG/1)

Comment: @revo yes you are right. I understood it after seeing answer from Wiktor Stribiżew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(([\*\+\-\/])([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*))+` pattern is an example of a *[repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)*. Since it matches the whole `+100*25-30` string capturing each pair of the match operator with the number after it, only the last occurrence captured is stored in the Group 1 (that is `-30`).

You can use

```php
preg_match_all("/([*+\/-]?)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)/", "+100*25-30", $match)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/FhoYY). Alternatively, `preg_match_all("/([*+\/-]?)([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)/", "+100*25-30", $match)`.

**See also the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/EGtAfC/1)**

*Details*:

- `([*+\/-]?)` - Group 1: an optional `*`, `+`, `/` or `-` char
- `([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)` - Group 2: zero or more digits, an optional `.` and one or more digits.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understood one thing. + at the end of my regex was my mistake. If I remove + at the end, it is working. In your regex, you added ? after operators : [*+\/-]? Why is ? needed here? It is must to exist at least one operator. I think ? means zero or more correct?

Comment: @Jamol I made the math operator optional. `?` matches 1 or 0 times, i.e. greedily, at least once, but the pattern can also go missing. If you do not use it, the number without an operator (say, at the start of a string) won't get matched. You might also consider `([*+\/-]|^)` instead of `([*+\/-]?)` if you need to explicitly match at the start of string or an operator.